# R: Two Identically Structured Excel Files Return Different Data Types in Data Frames

Tags: r, readxl

I have two different Excel files, `excel1` and `excel2`.

I am reading them in using separate but identical functions:

```
df1<- readxl::read_xlsx("excel1.xlsx", sheet= "Ad Awareness", skip= 7)
df2<- readxl::read_xlsx("excel2.xlsx", sheet= "Ad Awareness", skip= 7)
```

However, when I run `head()` on each, here is what df` returns:

```
calDate             Score
  <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2016-10-17 00:00:00  17.8
2 2016-10-18 00:00:00  17.2
3 2016-10-19 00:00:00  20.3
```

And here is what df2 returns:

```
  calDate Score
    <dbl> <lgl>
1   43025 NA   
2   43026 NA   
3   43027 NA
```

Any reason why the data type are being read-in different? There is nothing different about the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_xlsx()` will guess the variable types based on your data (see [here](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html) for more information).

So what you are describing could be due to:

- different amount of data in your different files (not enough data in one of them to get to a correct guess)
- changes you might have made in Excel to the cell format (those changes are not always visually obvious in Excel)

Without seeing your data, it is hard to give you more answer than this.

But you can control this with the `col_types` argument:

> col_types: Either ‘NULL’ to guess all from the spreadsheet or a
>             character vector containing one entry per column from these
>             options: "skip", "guess", "logical", "numeric", "date",
>             "text" or "list". If exactly one ‘col_type’ is specified, it
>             will be recycled. The content of a cell in a skipped column
>             is never read and that column will not appear in the data
>             frame output. A list cell loads a column as a list of length
>             1 vectors, which are typed using the type guessing logic from
>             ‘col_types = NULL’, but on a cell-by-cell basis.

Comment: Complete Excel error. Shut Excel down and started back up, re-read the data back in and it was magically able to read both files in the same format. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that worked. But when this doesn't work, you can always use `col_types` to set the variable types manually.

Comment: even if they are different data types? one was datetime, the other was a numeric... is there indexing in `col_types`? I tried passing `c("date" , "time")` and `list("date", "time")` and neither worked.

Comment: This https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html and the help files should help you. There is no indexing and you set the type by column.